# Why Does My For Loop In My If Statement Render My If Statement Useless?

Tags: php, html

I realize my code may be ugly as sin, but it was working up until this point and I'm stumped.  The If statement works fine on its own, but not when I throw the For loop in there.

This is the PHP:

```
if (!empty($cross)){ /* supposed to hide the empty form field */
$message .= "<tr><td width='185'><strong><em>Item<em></strong></td><td width='370'><strong><em>Type<em></strong></td><td width='185'><strong><strong><em>Qty<em></strong></strong></td></tr><tr><td  width='185'><strong>Cross Braces</strong></td><td width='185'>";
for ($i = 0, $cross_number = count($cross), $j = 0, $crossqty_number = count($crossqty); $i < $cross_number, $j < $crossqty_number; $i++,$j++) {
$message .= "$cross[$i]</td><td width='185'>$crossqty[$j]</td></tr><tr><td width='185'></td><td width='370'>"; /* supposed to add a new row for the rest of the array */
}
$message .= "</td></tr>"; 
}
```

I can not, for the life, of me figure out why the if statement is not working.  When the form field is left blank, it still shows up in the html email.  Why might this if statement not function properly?

This is killing me.  Literally the last thing that needs to be done on this form.  Any help would be awesome.  Thank you.

Comment: I would have thought you need to use && when comparing 2 different statements. "$i < $cross_number && $j < $crossqty_number"

Comment: I thought so too, but I found out that this way works, and I'm definitely not versed well enough in PHP to figure that one out, haha

Comment: 1) Try adding `var_export($cross);die();` inside the `if` and see what is the value of it. 2) Do you know how many times this `if` code is executed for one request (once or many)?

Comment: @RuslanBes 
Answer to 1): array ( 0 => '', )
Answer to 2): I am not 100% sure how many times the code is executed to be completely honest, but I'm pretty sure I have it set up so that it only runs once.  But there are multiple instances of this ``if`` code, just with different ``$var``s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$cross` array is `array ( 0 => '')` which means two things:

1. It is [not empty](https://3v4l.org/G8hpi) so the`if` statement returns `true`.
2. It has exactly one element so `for` loop will run at least once (if `$crossqty` is non-empty too)

If that array instance is considered "empty" by your business-logic then you probably should [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) it beforehand.

Comment: Maaaannn, that makes so much sense now.  Wow, thank you very much!
I changed ``if (!empty($cross))`` to ``if (!empty(array_filter($cross)))`` and now it works perfectly.
I really appreciate your help.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$cross[$i]` in `""` - that returns

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING
>   or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Try:

```
<?php
if (!empty($cross)){ /* supposed to hide the empty form field */
    $message .= "<tr><td width='185'><strong><em>Item<em></strong></td><td width='370'><strong><em>Type<em></strong></td><td width='185'><strong><strong><em>Qty<em></strong></strong></td></tr><tr><td  width='185'><strong>Cross Braces</strong></td><td width='185'>";
    for ($i = 0, $cross_number = count($cross), $j = 0, $crossqty_number = count($crossqty); $i < $cross_number, $j < $crossqty_number; $i++,$j++) {
        $message .= $cross[$i] . "</td><td width='185'>" . $crossqty[$j] . "</td></tr><tr><td width='185'></td><td width='370'>";
    }
    $message .= "</td></tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: I was using ``$cross[$i]`` in ``""`` previously and it was working fine.  The ``for`` loop acts as it should, but it's the ``if`` statement that's just completely being ignored.  Also, I tried what you suggested and it didn't make a difference that I could see.  Still the same issue.